# Мне необходимо поменять все целые значения во вложенном списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
person = int(input("Введите кол-во людей"))
cook_book = [
  ['салат',
      [
        ['картофель', 100, 'гр.'],
        ['морковь', 50, 'гр.'],
        ['огурцы', 50, 'гр.'],
        ['горошек', 30, 'гр.'],
        ['майонез', 70, 'мл.'],
  ]]]
```

Здесь мне необходимо умножить все цифры из вложенного списка в person, то есть заданное пользователем число.(по возможности было бы супер, если бы как новичку объяснили)

Чтобы получить примерно такой результат если person = 5.

```
Салат:
картофель, 500гр.
морковь, 250гр.
огурцы, 250гр.
горошек, 150гр.
майонез, 350мл.
```

Заранее огромное спасибо!
Ранее примерный результат немного неправильно написал

Comment: А что  вы не умеете - обращаться  к элементу списка, или в чём другом проблема?

Comment: Я не могу понять как мне одновременно поменять все целые значения внутри вложенного списка. Да и честно говоря не знаю как вывести именно такой результат чтобы не было квадратных скобок и кавычек.

Comment: Как поменять одно значение - понятно? Поменять все точно так же, только по очереди.

Comment: Из примера непонятно, как меняются значения. Вывести список без скобок - print(*list)

Comment: Квадратные скобки - это список. Элементы списка перебираются с помощью `for`: `for page in cook_book:` Дальше смотрите что у вас в `page`, разбираете на имя рецепта и собственно список рецептов: `name, recipes = page`. Дальше итерируетесь уже по рецептам `recipes` и т.д. пока не дойдёте собственно до весов. Как всё разберёте - тогда будете умножать и печатать.

Comment: MBo,@CrazyElf, спасибо ребята. Вы очень помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть вашей задачи, то у вас есть книга рецептов, и рассчитана она на одну порцию, а вы хотели бы рассчитать граммовки для приготовления блюда на N персон.Тогда вам скорее нужен словарь, а не список

```
N = int(input('>>>'))

cook_book = {
    'salat':

        [
            {
                "ingredient": "potato",
                "count": 10,
                "units": "gram"
            },
            {
                "ingredient": "carrot",
                "count": 20,
                "units": "gram"
            }
        ]

}

for dish in cook_book:
    for ingredient in cook_book[dish]:
        ingredient['count'] *= N

for dish in cook_book:
    print(dish)
    for information in cook_book[dish]:
        print(information['ingredient'], information['count'], information['units'])
    print()
```

Comment: Тут такая проблема, я только на начальной стадии изучения и до словарей еще не дошел, спасибо за решение